# Javascript Push to Array if Condition is Met

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following Foods Object:

```
var Foods = {
  "Fruits": [{
   "id": "1",
   "Name": "Granny Smith",
   "Category": "1"
  }, {
   "id": "2",
   "Name": "Raspberries",
   "Category": "1"
   }
],
 "Potatoes": [{
   "id": "3",
   "Name": "Maris Piper",
   "Category": "2"
  }, {
   "id": "4",
   "Name": "Charlotte",
   "Category": "2"
 }]
 }
```

What I would like to do is only push the produce that matches an id passed by a link.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cat" id="2" onClick="getCat(this.id)">Get Foods</a>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function getCat (id){
 result = [];
 for(let item in Foods) {
    if(Foods[item].id == id) {
        data[item].foreach(v=>result.push("<div class='box'><h2>" + 
        data[key].Name + "<br></div>"));
    }
  }
}

display();

function display() {
  alert(result);
}
```

So if a user hits the link (which has an id of 2), the result array should contain "Charlotte" and "Maris Piper" but I am just drawing a blank.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: what is your variable `result = [];` scope? is it a global scope?

Comment: Whats data ???? And js is typesafe, so its *onclick* and *forEach*

Comment: Sorry should be a Foods object.

Comment: I think you might be looking for *array.filter*, but it is completely unclear what your data looks like and what you want to get out of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Youre quite close, however theres a slight problem:

```
for(let item in Foods) {
  console.log(Foods[item]);
  /*
  [{
  "id": "1",
  "Name": "Granny Smith",
 "Category": "1"
   }, {
   "id": "2",
   "Name": "Raspberries",
   "Category": "1"
   }
]
*/
```

So youre iterating over the categories, which are arrays.

```
Foods[item].id
```

is undefined as its an array and not a product. So we need to iterate the array to, e.g.

```
var result=[];
Object.values(Foods).forEach(function(category){
 category.forEach(function(product){
   if(product.id===id){
     result.push(product);
   }
 });
});
```

[Run](http://jsbin.com/niwaxoleva/edit?output)

But if youre doing this quite often, it might be easier to create one product array once:

```
var products = Object.values(Foods).reduce((arr,cat)=>arr.concat(cat),[]);
```

So you can simply filter this whenever someone clicks a button:

```
var result = products.filter(product=>product.id === id);
```

[Run](http://jsbin.com/garahamasa/edit?output)

Comment: Did you mean to write `var category in Foods` instead of `of Foods` since of doesn't work on Objects.

Comment: @antonio smoljan *of doesnt work on objects* lol. everything in js is an object.

Comment: You are certainly right it is but, the for..of loop only supports iterable objects like arrays, not objects.

Comment: @antonio smoljan lol, always have used it like this, never noticed that it doesnt work :/ . thanks ;)

Comment: No problem great answer im upvoting it, just wanted to see if i was mistaken :)

Comment: Using your first code snippet, Jonas this actually works but the alert function spits out the contents of result twice?

Comment: @hexana where did you put the alert?

Comment: var result=[];
Object.values(Foods).forEach(function(category){
 category.forEach(function(product){
   if(product.id===id){
     result.push(product);
   }
 });
});  alert(result);

Comment: An amazing help.  Thanks so much.  It has been really annoying me and you have really explained it. thanks again Jonas.  Big green tick from me :)

Comment: @hexana by the way, you may change *id* to *category* based on your example... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're somewhat on the right track, but what's `data`? Why are you not doing anything with `result`? And you should be looking at the `Category` property rather than ID.

This'll work:

```
function getCat(id) {
    let result = [];

    for (let item in Foods) {
        if (Foods.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            Foods[item].forEach((food) => {
                if (food.Category == id) {
                    result.push(food);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tried your solution and if I do document.write(result) it returns [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @hexana yes its an object. 1) dont use document.write 2) simply build up a string like you already did in your code instead

Comment: Jonas do you have an example as I can't seem to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `result array` should be at global scope so that you can access it in another function, And in object you are having categories then each category has some data in array so after iterating over object, you need to iterate the items from array as well to get the value. Check the below code.

```
var result = [];
    function getCat(id){
     for(let item in Foods) {
        var foodItem = Foods[item];
        for(let i=0; i<foodItem.length; i++){
           if(foodItem[i].id == id) {
              result.push("<div class='box'><h2>" + foodItem[i].Name + "<br></div>"));
           } 
        }

      }
    }

function display() {
  alert(result);
}

display();
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is wrong. You should do it like this:

```
function getCat(id){
    result = [];
    for(let item in Foods) {
        Foods[item].forEach(function(each){
            if(each.id == id) { // you cmpare to the wrong target
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```